# Sum of a column if it contains multiple strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get the sum of a column based on whether it matches multiple strings. For example,

`pd.DataFrame({'key': ['b', 'b d', 'a', 'c t', 'a', 'b p'], 'data1': range(6)})`

I want to be able to get the sum for data1 column IF the strings in the key column contain 'b' and 'c'. The sum in this case would be 9.

Comment: `df.loc[df['key'].isin(['b','c']), 'data1'].sum()`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My question was probably not clear so I have edited it for more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using regex express and string accessor, .str with `contains`:

```
df.loc[df['key'].str.contains('b|c'), 'data1'].sum()
```

Output:

```
9
```